# Using Javascript to deny specific character in Textarea,

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a textarea and I want to prevent someone from putting xss data in it, during entry..   I need to do it, before it's submitted, because my site is ASP.NET and framework instantly throws an exception 
**"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client."**

if it gets posted, not allow me to clean it during posting.   So I need to do it via JavaScript before posting it.

I attempted this, thinking, maybe it would reject the key press, but it doesn't seem to work, the return false, doesn't do anything as it would for submits for example.

```
function CheckChar(event) {
    var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if (x == 60 || x == 62)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Then from the HTML I'm doing this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="SMSMessage" TextMode="multiline" onkeypress="CheckChar(event)" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `return`

```js
function CheckChar(event) {
    var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
    console.log(x)
    if (x == 60 || x == 62)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<textarea name="SMSMessage" rows="5" cols="50" id="SMSMessage" onkeypress="return CheckChar(event)"></textarea>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea, I'm not sleeping and totally missed it..    I found, I can't use check during key press, because if someone copy paste it, I need to validate all data.   I'll give it to ya, because it's what I asked, even though I can't use it that way..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different way, because I need to validate all data, just in case someone pasted text in the textarea.

```
<asp:TextBox id="SMSMessage" TextMode="multiline" onkeyup="validate(this)" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
```

With this javascript:

```
function validate(o) {
    if (o.value.indexOf('<') > -1)
        o.value = o.value.replace('<', '');
    if (o.value.indexOf('>') > -1)
        o.value = o.value.replace('>', '');
}
```